# Google App Engine ERROR Throttling refreshCfg with Gcloud MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

Continuous failed connection attempts errors are occurring in Google Cloud MySQL running on Google APP Engine with public IP.

These are some of the logs:

```
receiveTimestamp    resource.labels.module_id   resource.labels.project_id  resource.labels.version_id  resource.labels.zone    resource.type   severity    textPayload timestamp

2021-06-08T05:48:43.497385728Z  zzzzzzzzzz  xxxxxxx 4   eu5 gae_app ERROR   Throttling refreshCfg(xxxxxxx:europe-west1:yyyyyyyyy): it was only called 80.802µs ago  2021-06-08T05:48:43.494284Z

2021-06-08T05:19:08.394840567Z  zzzzzzzzzz  xxxxxxx 4   eu5 gae_app ERROR   Throttling refreshCfg(xxxxxxx:europe-west1:yyyyyyyyy): it was only called 42.519µs ago  2021-06-08T05:19:08.391909Z

2021-06-08T05:13:42.889911567Z  zzzzzzzzzz  xxxxxxx 4   eu5 gae_app ERROR   Throttling refreshCfg(xxxxxxx:europe-west1:yyyyyyyyy): it was only called 73.279µs ago  2021-06-08T05:13:42.888659Z

2021-06-08T04:47:07.470804269Z  zzzzzzzzzz  xxxxxxx 4   eu5 gae_app ERROR   Throttling refreshCfg(xxxxxxx:europe-west1:yyyyyyyyy): it was only called 85.928µs ago  2021-06-08T04:47:07.467377Z
```

I tried some different configurations of max_connections, pool_size, pool_timeout with no success.

I have consulted [this](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-sql-discuss/c/bYmPDeWpCPY/m/LWNXhR9uDgAJ) previous Issue.

And [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections) documentation.

Some help would be appreciated.

More information. The error is always preceded by this warning in the log record:

```
"protoPayload": {
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
"status": {},
"authenticationInfo": {
  "principalEmail": "bbbbbbbb@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
  "serviceAccountDelegationInfo": [
    {
      "firstPartyPrincipal": {
        "principalEmail": "app-engine-appserver@prod.google.com"
      }
    }
  ]
},
"requestMetadata": {
  "callerIp": "2600:1900:2001:12::8",
  "requestAttributes": {
    "time": "2021-06-09T05:59:27.400680Z",
    "auth": {}
  },
  "destinationAttributes": {}
},
"serviceName": "cloudsql.googleapis.com",
"methodName": "cloudsql.instances.connect",
"authorizationInfo": [
  {
    "resource": "instances/aaaaaaaaaaa",
    "permission": "cloudsql.instances.connect",
    "granted": true,
    "resourceAttributes": {}
  }
],
"resourceName": "instances/aaaaaaaaa",
"request": {
  "project": "bbbbbbb",
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlInstancesCreateEphemeralCertRequest",
  "instance": "zzzzzzzzz",
  "body": {}
},
"response": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SslCert",
  "kind": "sql#sslCert"
}
},
"insertId": "-rgtsssssssssss",
"resource": {
    "type": "cloudsql_database",
    "labels": {
    "region": "europe-west1",
    "project_id": "bbbbbbbb",
    "database_id": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
}
},
"timestamp": "2021-06-09T05:59:27.381352Z",
"severity": "NOTICE",
"logName": 
"projects/demosmf/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
"receiveTimestamp": "2021-06-09T05:59:27.746071609Z"
```

I think it has something to do with the management of ssl certificates.

I have verified that the application certificates are valid and have not expired

Comment: We are having the same issue with App Engine and Google Cloud SQL (postgres).  It seems to occur when new app engine instances are spinning up. We started noticing this around June 4th.

Answer (score 2):

This error has been reported via Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190934612).

You can follow the thread I mentioned above to track the progress.